# Serving a static html page from a single page react app with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react single page app, and am looking at serving a static html, SEO friendly landing page in the scenario where the user is not logged in. I'd like for that one page to be browsable by all search engines (the rest of the site is password protected to SEO doesn't matter.
I'm using react router, and can't find a way in the app to redirect the user to the static html file (which would hence be served server side) if the app finds they're not logged in.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some code or a sample of what you are working with?

Comment: I'm looking to do something like this: `function requireAuthHome(nextState, replace) {
    if (LoginStore.isLoggedIn()) {
        replace({
            pathname: 'feed',
            state: {nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}
        })

    }
else browserHistory.push(‘/index.html’);
}` where index.html is a simple html file outside the app. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could do in your router on the server. You can't do it in your React app, because that defeats the purpose of having JS-less content to serve (since you'd be using JS to deliver the "static" content).

If you don't have a server set up yet with a router, that will take some time. But once you do, a simple check in the route will suffice.

```
// in hapijs, for example:

handler(request, reply) {
   if (isAuthenticated(request)) {
     reply.view('dashboard')
   } else {
     reply.view('static_page')
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. No I don't have a server setup with a router since the app is mostly purely front end - I just serve the js with nginx . Any recommendations as to the easiest way to get that setup? I'm fairly new to SPAs and just have this basic use case I need to fill. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note - the app is mostly built and is not isomorphic - I know I should probably have made it so, but have been working for 6 months on it at this point and don't want to have to make the whole thing server side rendered if possible (which unless I'm mistaken is what you're suggesting?). Thanks!

Comment: If you want server rendered HTML you will need to have a server of some kind. If you want to make a decision based on authorization that serves either JS or static content, you will need a server. Maybe you could get away with Amazon's lambda services (serverless architecture). Without that, I would recommend always serving a home page that is static markup and independent of your React app, and serving your React app from the other URLs. But as I noted above, there is no way to make a decision in the browser's JS about whether or not to use the browser's JS. Does that make sense?